# Uninitialized Controller Constant in Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting a `uninitialized constant Project::Controller`. I've looked through the Rails docs and posts here on SO, but the code seems to be setup correctly. I am using `rails 5.1.1`.  My pages path works fine, only the root path gives the error.

**routes .rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :users,
             path: '',
             path_names: {
                 sign_in: 'login',
                 sign_out: 'logout',
                 edit: 'profile'
             },
             controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }

  get 'pages/about'

  root 'project/#index'

  resources :project do
    resources :task, only: [:show]
  end

end
```

**project_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @tasks = @project.tasks
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
root 'project/#index'
```

to

```
root 'project#index'
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something so obvious :) Thank you.